# java 8 jpeg conversion bug?

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedimage, image-conversion

Following topics on stackoverflow and this example : http://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-png-to-jpeg-image-file-in-java/

The code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("./1.jpg");
    //  File file = new File("./1.png");
    File out = new File("./2.jpg");

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

    BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = newBufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(newBufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
    g2.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", out);
}
```

Execut this code create an black jped picture with java 8.
This code worked with java 7

Bug in java 8 or changing API ?

Comment: did you want to say `g2.drawImage(image, ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this line is the problem:

```
g2.drawImage(newBufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
```

I think you're looking for:

```
g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
```

The original line was drawing the newly created `BufferedImage` onto itself instead of the loaded image.